# Function returning value 'NaN'

Tags: javascript

I am writing a code that checks the user input and gives the result according to it. But the twist here is that the string can also contain the word 'dozen', which just means twelve. The thing will be cleared after looking at the following code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>iRock</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label for="numDonut">Enter how many donuts you want:  </label>
            <input type="text" id="numDonut">
            <div id="totalDonuts"></div>
            <div id="submit" onclick="callDonut();">SUBMIT</div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
//Get string number of donuts entered
var numDonutString = document.getElementById('numDonut').value;

function getTotalDonuts(donutString){
    var initialDonutCount = parseInt(donutString);
    var finalDonuts = 0;

    if(donutString.indexOf('dozen') != -1)
        finalDonuts = initialDonutCount * 12;
    else
        finalDonuts = initialDonutCount;

    return finalDonuts;
}
function callDonut(){
    document.getElementById('totalDonuts').textContent = getTotalDonuts(numDonutString);
}
```

Now here is the problem : No matter what input I give, even if it doesn't contain the word 'dozen', the function returns NaN, which is not making sense.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, seems to work fine.

Comment: Post your input please. Are you sure the input is a number ?

Comment: You assumed that `parseInt` will always return a number - it won't. It returns `NaN` in case it can't understand the input and coerce it correctly. Do a `console.log(initialDonutCount);` just after your call to `parseInt` and check what you get.

Comment: say I input the number 2, it returns NaN

Comment: @Mjh, I read somewhere that if in parseInt if you give a string that contains both a number and a string, it returns the number with changed data type, is this wrong?

Comment: Yes, if you *give* it what you wrote. You're giving it something else, which is the reason it can't do much with the data it gets hence it gives a `NaN` back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the function `callDonut` like :

```
function callDonut(){
    document.getElementById('totalDonuts').textContent = getTotalDonuts(document.getElementById('numDonut').value);
}
```

The problem: you don't reassign the new value of your input into the variable `numDonutString`

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are having is you have tried to pre define your `var numDonutString = document.getElementById('numDonut').value;` however what this does is takes a copy of the value and it will never update that value.

So what you need to do is get the new value each time you click the `SUBMIT` button.

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/xue6sbz2/

```
function getTotalDonuts(donutString){
    alert(donutString);
    var initialDonutCount = parseInt(donutString);
    var finalDonuts = 0;

    if(donutString.indexOf('dozen') != -1)
        finalDonuts = initialDonutCount * 12;
    else
        finalDonuts = initialDonutCount;

    return finalDonuts;
}

function callDonut(){
    document.getElementById('totalDonuts').textContent = getTotalDonuts(document.getElementById('numDonut').value);
}
```

Comment: Thnx a lot for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `callDonut` function and the text box value you are getting is only at the document load, so the value is always `NaN`.

```js
window.getTotalDonuts = function(donutString) {
  var initialDonutCount = parseInt(donutString);
  var finalDonuts = 0;
  if (donutString.indexOf('dozen') != -1) {
    finalDonuts = initialDonutCount * 12;
  } else {
    finalDonuts = initialDonutCount;
  }
  return finalDonuts || 0;
}

window.callDonut = function() {
  //Get string number of donuts entered
  var numDonutString = document.getElementById('numDonut').value;
  document.getElementById('totalDonuts').textContent = getTotalDonuts(numDonutString);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="numDonut">Enter how many donuts you want:</label>
  <input type="text" id="numDonut">
  <div id="totalDonuts"></div>
  <div id="submit" onclick="callDonut();">SUBMIT</div>
</form>
</body>
```

<kbd>[DEMO][1]</kbd>